# Is it possible to run sudo with HEREDOC?

Tags: shell, sudo, here-document

Edit: Amended examples after @Kusalananda answer. My whole picture is more complex. I need multiple commands and a variable definition)

I can't use `su` because I'm not root and I don't want to input a password

I tried mimicking the su code coming from a fellow's script:

```bash
# script runs as root
su - oracle -- "export DATA=$val; cat <<CHK
test 
CHK"
Password:
test
```

The following does not work (wrong output):

```bash
$ export val=534
$ sudo -i -u oracle -- "export DATA=$val;cat <<CHK
test
CHK"
-ksh: export DATA=534;cat <<CHKtestCHK: not found
[127]$
```

Neither this (no output at all):

```bash
$ sudo -i -u oracle -- ksh -c "export DATA=$val;cat <<CHK
test
CHK"
$
```

I understand that somehow `sudo` is *flattening* the input, but [man sudo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html) only mentions this for arguments and separated by spaces, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make the here-document redirection part of the command that you execute with `sudo`:

```bash
sudo -u oracle env DATA="$val" cat <<END
this is
the here-document
END
```

The `sudo` utility will pass the standard input stream to the command it executes. The `env` tool modifies the environment before executing the given utility. Using it with `sudo`, like shown above, is one way of setting environment variables in the utility that you want to run with `sudo` even though `sudo` may be clearing the environment from most variables.

If your command is more complex than setting a variable and running `cat`, consider collecting the operations you need to execute with `sudo` in a script, then run that script.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

export DATA="something"

cat <<END
this is
the here-document
END
```

Note that the string `something` could also be taken from the script's command line. Or you may leave out that statement altogether and instead set `DATA` with `env` as shown before, as you are executing the script:

```bash
sudo env DATA="$var" ./myscript
```

Comment: Beware though that if on Linux or Cygwin, if the command (not `cat`) tries to open `/dev/stdin` (like `cat /dev/stdin`), that will fail so that could be a case where you'd want to create the heredoc as the target user (for which you'd need to start a shell as the target user)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I guess it is my use case (sqlplus)

Comment: @MatM If you have clarifications to your question, please add these to your question.  I saw that you added a `DATA` environment variable to your code, so I updated my answer accordingly.